# BubblePopupHelper filling Android Debug Log

Tags: android, debugging, logcat, android-logcat

So I noticed when I was debugging that there seems to be a tag that's repeating through my app entitled "BubblePopupHelper" with text: "isShowingBubblePopup : false"

Screenshot of the log
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nZcn.png]

To my knowledge, I'm not using or causing it. Does anyone have an idea of what's going on? The application is the one I'm writing.

Upon further inspection, I did notice that every time I'm updating text (via a TextView) it displays onscreen. If there's a better way of doing so, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you perform a search in your code to see where the log statement is located?  When you find it just comment it out.

Comment: @adavis
None of the tags I'm using are BubblePopupHelper, so I'm not creating them manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message seems to be logged by some SDK libraries whenever setText is called in a TextView. I get it in Android Studio developing with min API 14. 
One interim solution till Google removes it would be using the filtering feature of Android Studio by writing a RegEx that only includes your log messages. For example if I have all my tags start with 'Braim' then 'Braim.*' can be used

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to filter this annoying logs away you can use the following regex:

*by Log Tag:*  `(?!^BubblePopupHelper)(^.*$)`

Answer (score 1):

Have you added "OnGlobalLayoutListener"?

I've encountered same problem and finally I found that getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener caused the problem.

Here is my solution:

```
    textView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            ...

            textCategory.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't believe I added the OnGlobalLayoutListener.
I fixed the issue at one point and wasn't sure what I did, so that very well could have been the issue.